# How to use a themeForest theme with MeteorJs

Tags: meteor, custom-theme

I have a theme  bought at theme Forest, and  would love to use it in my new meteors project.Can someone kindly walk me through how one canimplement and use it in a project.Thanks

Comment: I think you are asking more like a tutorial than a SO answer isnt?, but well if you buy a theme on theme forest, did you make sure the maintener of the package support Meteor? if no you will have a bad time integrating everything into a layout structure, templates, iron router, etc.

Comment: Am not necessarily needing a tutorial, am asking help from anyone who has ever hacked integrating a theme with meteor what are the best practises to follow.thanks

Comment: What kind of theme you've purchased? Wordpress? HTML?

Comment: @Ryan a HTML theme!!!